# Lisp grade to letter conversion

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Question asked:

```
Define a LISP function SCORE->GRADE which takes a single argument, s, and returns a symbol according to the following scheme:
 s ≥ 90 A           73 ≤ s < 77 C+
 87 ≤ s < 90 A–     70 ≤ s < 73 C
 83 ≤ s < 87 B+     60 ≤ s < 70 D
 80 ≤ s < 83 B      s < 60 F
 77 ≤ s < 80 B–
 If the argument s is not a number then the function should return NIL.
```

My answer is this:

```
 (defun SCORE->GRADE (s)
        (if (not (numberp s))  (return-from SCORE->GRADE “NIL”))
        (progn 
        (if (>= s 90) (return-from SCORE->GRADE "A"))
        (if (and (>= s 87) (< s 90)) (format nil “A-“))
        (if (and (>= s 83) (< s 87)) (format nil “B+”))
        (if (and (>= s 80) (< s 83)) (return-from SCORE->GRADE “B”))
        (if (and (>= s 77) (< s 80)) (return-from SCORE->GRADE “B-“))
        (if (and (>= s 73) (< s 77)) (return-from SCORE->GRADE “C+”))
        (if (and (>= s 70) (< s 73)) (return-from SCORE->GRADE “C”))
        (if (and (>= s 60) (< s 70)) (return-from SCORE->GRADE “D”)
        (if (< s 60) (return-from SCORE->GRADE “F”)) 
        )
      )
    )
```

It works for 90, returns A, then for anything else it just gives this error, with different variables in regards to what I enter

> *** - RETURN-FROM: variable “B” has no value
>
> *** - IF: variable “A-“ has no value

Can anyone explain why I can't get the same result for every line that is incredibly identical?

I've tried message, format t, cases, some work for up to the first 3 cases then stop. Haven't been able to figure anything out.

Comment: In the code, which you posted, it looks like the line with `"A"` uses different quotation marks than the rest. But I don't know, if that could be the cause.

Comment: It's worth noting that all the answers so far are wrong as they've not read the question carefully enough. In particular: what is meant to be returned?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to other answers, note that in your case you do not need to duplicate common boundaries, since you are trying to partition scores into grades.

```
(cond
  ((>= s 90) "A")
  ((>= s 87) "A-")
  ((>= s 83) "B+")
  ...
  ((>= s 70) "C")
  ((>= s 60) "D")
  (t "F"))
```

It also reduces the number of invariants you have to keep in your code, which helps with maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

when you fixed your problem with the double quotes, here are some additional hints:

- you usually don't need to use `RETURN-FROM` in Lisp.
- checking multiple conditions is best done with `COND` and not by multiple `IF` statements.
- functions like `>=`, `>`, ... can take more than two arguments.

see for example:

```
(cond ((not (numberp s)) NIL)
      ((>=    s 90)  "A" )
      ((>= 90 s 87)  "A-")
      ((>= 87 s 83)  "B+")
      ((>= 83 s 80)  "B" )
      ;...
      ((>= 60 s   )  "F" ))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using the character `“` instead of `"` to wrap the strings.

Comment: Explains everything... I would copy paste it into text editor and fix it there and move it over and didn't even realize those were different. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea as @coredump.

```
(defun SCORE->GRADE (s)
  (cond ((not (numberp s)) nil)
        ((>= s 90) "A")
        ((>= s 87) "A-")
        ((>= s 83) "B+")
        ((>= s 80) "B")
        ((>= s 77) "B-")
        ((>= s 73) "C+")
        ((>= s 70) "C")
        ((>= s 60) "D")
        (t "F")))
```

Which again can be slightly more elegantly formulated as:

```
(defun SCORE->GRADE (s)
  (when (numberp s)
    (cond ((>= s 90) "A")
          ((>= s 87) "A-")
          ((>= s 83) "B+")
          ((>= s 80) "B")
          ((>= s 77) "B-")
          ((>= s 73) "C+")
          ((>= s 70) "C")
          ((>= s 60) "D")
          (t "F"))))
```